# Give error if more than one file opened

Tags: vimrc, multiple-files

I usually don't use Vim's multiple-files features. If I open Vim on multiple files, it is usually user error. For example, a common mistake of mine is that I end up entering the following:

```
vim vim somefile.txt
```

How can I add something to `.vimrc` to receive an error, and exit Vim, when I call Vim with multiple files? I currently do the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
function vim ()
{
  if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Scott: did you really want to open Vim with more than one file?" >&2
    return 1
  else
    /usr/bin/vim "$@"
  fi
}
```

However, this is not ideal since if I use an argument, it will be falsely detected by my function as another file. I could make the above function a bit smarter, but I'm guessing there's a better way to do this in `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
if bufnr("$") > 1
    echo "MORE THAN ONE FILE"
endif
```

The `bufnr('$')` returns the buffer number for the last buffer.   If you only have one buffer open, then the last buffer number should equal the first buffer number...and they could both equal 1.  If the last buffer number is greater than 1, then you have more than one buffer open.

Comment: You could also look at argc, which i think should give the count of :args

Comment: Works great! I also added `cq 1` after the `echo`.